# how to use HEAD method of HTTPClient to get all headers

Tags: java, header, http-headers, httpclient, head

I have to use `HEAD` method of `HttpClient` to get the header field and to check the "last-modified" date of server file.
I am not able to get that, if you know how to get the header field then please reply.
How to get the "last-modified" header into the String object for the comparison.

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
//HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpHead method = new HttpHead(url);
HttpResponse response= client.execute(method);

Header[] s = response.getAllHeaders();

System.out.println("THe header from the httpclient:");
for(int i=0; i < s.length; i++){
    Header hd = s[i];
    System.out.println("Header Name: "+hd.getName()
                        +"       "+" Header Value: "+ hd.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On httpClient 4.5 you would use:

```
final HttpHead headMethod = new HttpHead(fileUri);
final Header header = headMethod.getFirstHeader("last-modified");
final String lastModified = header.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the HttpClient [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/head.html)

```
HeadMethod head = new HeadMethod("http://jakarta.apache.org");

// Excecute the method here with your HttpClient

Header[] headers = head.getResponseHeaders();
String lastModified = head.getResponseHeader("last-modified").getValue();
```

You'll need to add your own error handling.

Comment: yes, this is write but when I used it  I getting the following error.  ........HeadMethod cannot be resolved to a type. could you tell me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: is it write but when I used this I getting following errors.         HeadMethod cannot be resolved to a type. How shoud I overcome this problem. please reply..

Comment: @ShashiShirke, you need to download the Apache commons http client library, and include it in your project.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use something like this:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpHead head = new HttpHead(url);
String lastModified;
try {
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(head);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        Header header = headMethod.getFirstHeader("last-modified");
        lastModified = header.getValue();
    }
} catch (IOException ignored) {
}
```