# Auto monitoring a web page changes

Tags: java

I'm using java console application. I want to monitor a web site. If any changes happens in certain webpage a process will be invoke. How is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by change in web page?

Comment: you should elaborate your question, specify which type of changes, is your console application paired with website in any way ..stuff like that !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `httpclient` to 'get' the html content of the webpage as a `String`, then use `String.equals()` method to compare the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient to get the head of a remote file (like a web page). Then parse the `last-modified` header and compare it to the last known date.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820107/748524) for details.