# How to cache image downloaded from URL in Java?

Tags: java, image, url, caching

I have downloaded an image from a URL  using ImageIO.write, so now I am wondering if there was a possibility of somehow caching that image. Is there a possibility to compare the downloaded image with the URL it's downloaded from to know that the image is from that URL? I need this because if I download an image and than later call that same URL for downloading, my app can recognize that it already has the image downloaded, so it doesn't download it again.

Comment: You can develop your own service to do that. For example, you can keep a `HashSet<String>` of the URLs of already downloaded images. The problem is that if the image changes, you will not get the refreshed image.

Comment: He can do a [HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819975/how-to-use-head-method-of-httpclient-to-get-all-headers) request and can check the last modified date of the file. In the hash, he should store the local image (or its local path), the original url (as key) and the previous last modified date, if he knows it, he will know when to refresh the image after comparing the stored and the fetched dates.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to see if you can integrate the code to upload the picture to google and search by image. Or, you can also save the url of the image with an array while storing the image if you have multiple images you want to download at once.